# How to use predefined Spinner style classes in FXML

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml, javafx-css

According to [this Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#spinner) javaFX 8u45 spinner, can be styled in numerous ways via style class. I do know how to do it by code.

For example:

```
spinner.getStyleClass().add(Spinner.STYLE_CLASS_SPLIT_ARROWS_HORIZONTAL);
```

or,

```
spinner.getStyleClass().add("split-arrows-horizontal");
```

However, not by fxml. I did try this, but it did not work. I did this via scenebuilder, version 8.

```
<Spinner fx:id="spn" editable="true" styleClass="split-arrows-horizontal"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why but defining `styleClass` in FXML like

```
<Spinner fx:id="spn" styleClass="split-arrows-horizontal"/>
```

will not result adding that style to styleClass list. You can check it by

```
@FXML private Spinner spn;

@Override
public void initialize( URL url, ResourceBundle rb )
{
    System.out.println( "getStyleClass: " + spn.getStyleClass() );
}
```

**However**, defining it in FXML as

```
<Spinner fx:id="spn">
     <styleClass>
        <String fx:value="split-arrows-horizontal" />
     </styleClass>
</Spinner>
```

works as expected.

Comment: Works like charm, works great on scene builder 8, on the negative side this cant be done from scene builder it self, i had to write it from text editor

Comment: Ok i got it to work from scene builder 8 itself, i added two style classes ("split-arrows-horizontal" and a dummy style class that doesnt change anything), and it worked, a discovery here is that these pre defined java fx style classes will not work in fxml unless it is with another legit or non existing style class

Comment: Glad to hear that @jyonkheel. I almost never used scene builder so can't tell smthng about it.